# Convergence and finer topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Can convergent of sequence be used to determine which topology is finer(in general topological space).
I am asking this is question in effect of theorem on metric space: 'topology 1 is finer than topology 2(both on same set) if and only if all cgt sequences in 1 also convergent in 2 to same limit'. and is it true or not if we remove same limit condition from the theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, indeed. Certain types of topological spaces, such as metric spaces, have the characteristic that the convergence behavior of sequences determines the topology exactly. Such spaces are called [sequential spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space).

Comment: ya right. But can we say anything about topological space. Or we can give counterexample of a topological space where this theorem does not hold

Comment: @Sushil on the link in this answer you can find:"An example of a space that is not sequential is the cocountable topology on an uncountable set"

Comment: A counterexample is to consider, for example, the real line, but not under the usual topology. Instead, we say that a subset of the real line will be open iff it is either empty or has a countable complement. (Countable, meaning countably infinite or finite.) It can be shown that if a sequence converges to a point $x,$ then all but finitely many of the sequence terms are equal to $x,$ so that all but finitely many of the sequence terms lie in $\{x\},$ but this is not an open set. Follow the link for more information.

Comment: One minute @CameronBuie only cgt sequence in cocountable topology are eventually constant. This is okay but how it serves as counterexample to theorem written above for topological space. I didn't get which second metric we are choosing

Comment: @drhab sorry didn't get how it serves as counterexaple

Comment: @CameronBuie I am asing if the foloowing theorem true in a topological space: 'topology 1 is finer than topology 2(both on same set) if and only if all cgt sequences in 1 also convergent in 2 to same limit

Comment: The proof that sequences are eventually constant in cocountable topology with uncountable set. That I got

Comment: @Sushil: Sorry about that! So, all convergent sequences are eventually constant, yes? But this is also true of the discrete space on the reals. In other words, the two spaces have *exactly the same convergence behavior*, but are not identical spaces. If the theorem held in general, each would be finer than the other, and so they would *have* to be identical. The problem is that the cocountable topology on the reals is not metrizable, so the theorem doesn't apply.

Comment: Thanks got it now. Discrete topology and cocountable topology have same cgt sequence. But cocountable topology is not finer than discrete topology. And one part of theorem is true(when we assume one topology finer)

Comment: @Sushil: True, the converse does hold in general.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X$ be a non-empty set with two metrics $d$ and $e$, and $\tau_d$, $\tau_e$ their induced topologies. You need to show that the following two are equivalent:

$$
d(x_n,x)\to 0 \,\,\Longrightarrow\,\, e(x_n,x)\to 0,
$$ 
and
$$
\tau_e\subset \tau_d.
$$

"$\Longrightarrow$" It suffices to show that if $C\subset X$ is $e-$closed, then it is also $d-$closed. Let $C\subset X$ be $e-$closed and $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset C$, with $d(x_n,x)\to 0$. We need to show that $x\in C$. But $d(x_n,x)\to 0$ implies that $e(x_n,x)\to 0$ and hence $x\in C$, as $C$ is $e-$closed.

"$\Longleftarrow$" Assume that $\tau_e\subset \tau_d$ and $d(x_n,x)\to 0$. We need to show that $e(x_n,x)\to 0$. If not there exists an $\varepsilon>0$, such that for every $n_0$, there exists a $n\ge n_0$ satisfying
$$
e(x_n,x)\ge \varepsilon.
$$
In this way we can construct a subsequence $\{x_{k_n}\}$ of $\{x_n\}$ satisfying
$$
e(x_{k_n},x)\ge \varepsilon, \quad \text{for all $n$.}
$$
So
$$
\{x_{k_n}\} \subset \{y\in X: e(x,y)\ge\varepsilon\}=C.
$$
But clearly $C$ is a $e-$closed set and hence, as $\tau_e\subset\tau_d$, a $d-$closed set as well. Thus, the $d-$limit of $\{x_{k_n}\}$ should be in $C$. But the   $d-$limit of $\{x_{k_n}\}$ is $x$, and $x\not\in C$.

Comment: This is okay but is this theorem true in general topological space

Comment: @Sushil: Indeed it is true, and the proof is very similar and simpler.

Comment: @Yirogos S. Smyrlis No this is not true in general topological space as Cameron Bluie gave counterexample in other comment.